# Mongoid update_attributes not getting persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Here is a simple Model.

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :schedule, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :active, type: Boolean, default: true
  key :name

end
```

1.We create and event

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > event = Event.new(:name => "event1")
 => #<Event _id: event1, _type: nil, _id: "event1", name: "event1", schedule: nil, description: nil, active: true> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > event.save!
 => true
```

2.Know lets find the event

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > event = Event.find("event1")
=> #<Event _id: event1, _type: nil, _id: "event1", name: "event1", schedule: nil, description: nil, active: true>
```

3.So update event attributes

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > event.update_attributes!(:name => "new name")
 => true
```

4.Lets try to find the event

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > event = Event.find("new name")
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: Document not found for class Event with id(s) new name.
```

5.Ooops not found, but the old one is still persisted

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > event = Event.find("event1")
 => #<Event _id: event1, _type: nil, _id: "event1", name: "event1", schedule: nil, description: nil, active: true>
```

**What I am doing wrong ? I hope this is not a bug.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe MongoDB lets you alter an `_id` field. When I try it using the standard mongo shell, I get this error (meaning it's not a Mongoid limitation, it's a limitation in the actual Mongo software):

```
Mod on _id not allowed
```

Whenever you need to alter the `name` field, you'll probably need to:

1. Copy it to a new record with the new name.
2. Delete the old record

Comment: Yep to bad is not in the docs, I decided to allow this, I just check if the key is getting updated, if so duplicate the document, change the key, save the new doc and delete the old one, that way the user gets exactly what he wants.